# Does Arraylist .contains method work on Arraylist with multiple parameters

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

Lets say I have a custom Arraylist "al" with parameters "name" , "sex" , number, and I added the following items into the Arraylist:

```
al.add(new AL("xvc","yes pls",112233));
al.add(new AL("tww","no thanks",44532));
al.add(new AL("wrr","yes pls",88643));
```

Does the `.contains` method work on such an lists? So far, all the examples of the `.contains` method only work with a simple String or int list. My own tests with various ways of using the method have returned false thus far.

My ultimate goal is to search whether an element in the array has the value of "wrr". I figured I could do it by building alongside a hashmap, but I wonder if there's any method within ArrayList that can do the same simple search.

Comment: Does `AL` implement `equals(AL other)` and `hashCode()` (correctly)?

Comment: @deHaar no i have not implement the two said methods. its just a simple AL class with constructor , setter and getter. the only way that i'm doing for another arraylist is by generating a new hashmap to be in sync with the arraylist everytime it gets updated and i thought its not very neat. and sometimes prone to be out of sync.

Comment: @GaëlJ this looks interesting and something new to me. may be one way to solve my problem. thanks for the link and time for me to do more learning!

Comment: Well, `contains` needs to check for equality, hence, the `equals(...)` method must be implemented, at least. I think `hashCode()` might be involved, too, but I'm not quite sure ;-) By the way, primitives are compared with `==`, but `String` is not a primitive, it has an `equals(String other)` method implemented. That's why `contains(String s)` works in an `ArrayList<String>`.